# Extracting theorems into images

Tags: environments, automation, extract

Is it possible to automatically export all theorems to single files, say PNG or other image formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to automatically export all theorems to a single new document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46179/154418

After that, you could use a `\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{\pagebreak}`, which should yield you one theorem per page.

Now, for the image part, using the `convert` option of the `standalone` class will directly output to PNG, with transparency:

`\documentclass[convert]{standalone}`

If you want one image per page, it might be simpler to chain it with a PDF to multiple PNG external tool, depending on what's available on your system.